# Using time() inside a while loop

Tags: php

For a school assignment we need to write a PHP script that counts for 1 second.

The following code I wrote should do exactly that was my thought:

```
$startTijd = time();
$teller = 0;
while($startTijd == time()){
    echo 'Iteratie: ' . $teller . '<br>';
    $teller++;
}
```

However, every time I run this or any PHP script similar to it that uses the time() function inside a while loop I get a 502 bad request from the server when I try to visit the page.

Comment: Are going to write it on PHP or javascript?

Comment: It must be written in PHP.

Comment: the loop will most likely not even be executed. There probably is a syntax error somewhere, check your server logs

Comment: Doing this with PHP is okay but for more flexibility and good performance i suggest you to do this with JavaScript and after every second you can use ajex to store data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as it is would not work (would not count one second exactly), because `time()` has a granularity of one second, and you have no guarantees that you landed on your page exactly at the tick of a second. So you need to synchronize.

To be clear, imagine calling `time()` several times, and let's suppose `time()` outputs in HH:MM:SS instead of Unix timestamps for legibility's sake:

```
Code
print time()
print time()
print time()
...

Output:
01:15:17
01:15:17
01:15:17
...
01:15:18
01:15:18
01:15:18
...
```

Your program probably currently does not work correctly because even in the little time that the loop runs, it generates a fantastic quantity of output (as can be seen above, `time()` remains "valid" for up to a whole second, and in that time a loop can execute *lots* of times). If there's some sort of resource limit on the PHP process, it's possible that this drives the process over its quota, resulting in the 502 error. You can check that by removing the `echo` from the loop, and just adding `echo "Done."` at the end.

You want to count between the instant in time in which `time()` transitions from 01:15:17 to 01:15:18, up to the instant when it again transitions to 01:15:19. *Those* instants will be separated by exactly one second.

What you would need to do is:

```
$startTijd = time()+1; // It is now maybe 01:15:17.93. We want to start
                       // counting at 01:15:18, so we need to wait for it.
while($startTijd !== time()) {
    // Do nothing except maybe a very brief sleep to save CPU
    usleep(5); // this is optional anyway.
}
// It is now 01:15:18.000003 and $startTijd is 01:15:18
$teller = 0;
// time() will remain equal to 01:15:18 for one second,
// while wall clock time increases from 01:15:18.000003 to 01:15:18.999999
while ($startTijd == time()) {
    // Don't output anything here
    $teller++;
}
// New transition detected.
// It is now e.g. 01:15:19.000137 and time() says 01:15:19.
echo 'Iteratie: ' . $teller . '<br>';
```

Alternately you can use `microtime(true)`:

```
$teller = 0;
$endTijd = microtime(true) + 1.0;
while ($endTijd >= microtime(true)) {
    // Don't output anything here
    $teller++;
}
echo 'Iteratie: ' . $teller . '<br>';
```

Comment: We are bound to using time(). I suppose the best way to echo every number in $teller is to make an array that stores the count in every iteration of the while (approx 12118959). Or will this array get to big?

Comment: Then you must use time() twice, the first to synchronize with the clock and start counting at the beat of a second, the other to stop counting at the *end* of the second. But why output the *whole* count? Isn't the final value enough? (Yes, such an array is likely very big. Depends on what the server allows you to do).

Comment: I am starting to doubt looking at the complexity of the solution that I understood the assignment correctly. I will just make it output the final count. Just one question remains, am I right when I assume that PHP builds up the entire block inside any type of loop inside memory instead of starting from scrap every iteration in memory?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question. The PHP code will be compiled only once, then the loop will start outputting data; this output goes to the browser, optionally passing through other layers in memory depending on server configuration, buffering, compressione etc.; all these blocks compromise between resource usage and performances. You can avoid buffering and save hugely in memory, but the page loading will be slower; or eschew compression and save CPU cycles, and the page loading will be **waaay** slower.

Comment: Your reply made it clear enough. Thanks for the help. Marking this one as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense... your while statment is only true if you computer is fast enough.

```
$startTijd = 100; # you set here the time represented by a number

while(100 == time() #101) { # here time is some milliseconds or seconds in the future
```

so after a second your while stops so that make not so much sense. Then use

```
while(true) {
```

and stop the while with a condition insight the while loop.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to say but I think I am getting confused. How would comparing the time to a starting time inside the while be any faster (time() return the time in seconds)? `code`$startTijd = time();
$teller = 0;
$run = true;
while($run){
    if($startTijd == time()){
        echo 'Iteratie: ' . $teller;
        $teller++;
    } else {
        $run = false;
    }
}`code` Does not work either.

Comment: You're right, but *almost any computer today is more than fast enough*. `time()` returns whole seconds. You're perhaps thinking of `microtime(true)`.